# Can't load image ( carousels ) in Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js, carousel

this is my code :

```
<template>
  <div class="heroBlock">
    <v-carousel hide-delimiters height="400px" cycle>
      <v-carousel-item
          v-for="(item,i) in items"
          :key="i"
          :src="item.src"
          reverse-transition="fade-transition"
          transition="fade-transition"
      ></v-carousel-item>
    </v-carousel>
  </div>



</template>

<script>
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      items: [
        {
          src: require("../test/src/assets/images/carousel1.jpg"),
        },
        {
          src: require("../test/src/assets/images/carousel1.jpg") ,
        },
        {
          src: require("../test/src/assets/images/carousel1.jpg"),
        },
        {
          src: require("../test/src/assets/images/carousel1.jpg"),
        },
      ],
    }
  },
}
</script>

<style scoped>
<
```

but give me this error

> ERROR  Failed to compile with 1 errors                                                                                                                                            1:30:58 PM

This relative module was not found:

- ../test/src/assets/images/carousel1.jpg in ./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--12-0!./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/cache-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--0-0!./node_modu
  les/vue-loader/lib??vue-loader-options!./src/components/Routes/Navbar/Home/NewHome.vue?vue&type=script&lang=js&

but if i enter this part give me no error:

```
            src: 'https://cdn.vuetifyjs.com/images/carousel/squirrel.jpg',
```

what's the problem??

Comment: can you test your path outside of carousel?

Comment: You probably should require('~/assets/images/carousel1.jpg') using the ~ notation to represents the root of your project.

Comment: drocha87  that's not working but @ is right